# Trying to timeout when calling requestLocationUpdates when trying to get the last location update

Tags: android

Android Studio 3.4

I am using the `FusedLocationProviderClient` to get the coordinates for latitude and lontitude.

However, scenario I am testing is when the user turns off there location under settings. This would generally clear any location data when it is turned on again.

In the following snippet I am trying to handle this scenario by requesting location updates. However, the app will not get any last updates and I would like the request to time out. I have created the `LocationResult` with `setExpirationDuration` thinking this could timeout after 10 seconds if I set it to 10000 ms. But nothing happened.

```
 private fun getLocationFused() {
        fusedLocationProviderClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this)

        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) !=
                PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
            ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) !=
                PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, arrayOf(android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION), permissionRequestCode)
        }
        else {
            fusedLocationProviderClient.lastLocation.addOnSuccessListener(this) { location ->
                if(location != null) {
                    forecastPresenter.requestWeatherForecast(location.latitude, location.longitude)
                }
                else {
                    val locationCallback = object : LocationCallback() {
                        override fun onLocationResult(locationResult: LocationResult) {
                            forecastPresenter.requestWeatherForecast(locationResult.lastLocation.latitude, locationResult.lastLocation.longitude)
                            fusedLocationProviderClient.removeLocationUpdates(this)
                        }
                    }

                    val locationResult = LocationRequest()
                    locationResult.maxWaitTime = 10000
                    fusedLocationProviderClient.requestLocationUpdates(locationResult, locationCallback, null)
                }
            }.addOnFailureListener(this) {
                println(it.message)
            }.addOnCanceledListener(this) {
                println("Cancelled")
            }
        }
    }
```

If the event was to timeout after, what method would be called? Would the `onLocationResult` return with a nul `locationResult`?

Many thanks for any suggestions,

Comment: Maybe you can try the `setMaxWaitTime()` method. According to the doc,  it _Sets the maximum wait time in milliseconds for location updates._

https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/LocationRequest#setMaxWaitTime(long)

Comment: @Lodoss, I have tried that. But wondering what event I can capture after timeout occurs? Would it be the case of the null location result in the onLocationResult after timeout? Just wondering as when I tried nothing happened. So cannot handle a timeout issue

Comment: I just saw that you wrapped your `LocationCallback` in a `OnSuccessListener`. Because the provider won't fetch successfully the location, the success listener might not be called, right? If so, your request location updates won't stop. I'm not very familiar with the location process, but maybe you can try to remove the success listener. Refer to this [tuto](https://developer.android.com/training/location/receive-location-updates#kotlin) too.

Comment: @Lodoss I have updated my answer. I think you are right about wrapping the `LocationCallBack` in the `OnSuccessListener` I have added the `addOnFailureListener` and `addOnCancelledListener` which is chained, However, the timeout fails to trigger the `failureListener` and `cancelledListener`.

Comment: @Lodoss Basically, what I am trying to do is just handle the timeout so the app isn't left hanging waiting for the location to be success. During the timeout period if I open google maps the `onLocationResult` will trigger with the updated location. However, in my case I just want to timeout after about 10 seconds if no location is updated.

Comment: You are trying to print some variable content, in the failure callback. Can you print a simple string (such as "Failure"), instead? Just to be sure that the callback is fired or not.

Comment: Also, after a few research on my side, it seems that the location request updates can only be stopped when the activity is paused/stopped.

Comment: any update on this? I'm facing the same issue where I'm using [setDurationMillis()](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/CurrentLocationRequest.Builder#public-currentlocationrequest.builder-setdurationmillis-long-durationmillis) but nothing happened when the request exceeded the duration.

Comment: @moonLander_ I have started a bounty maybe we will get an updated answer.

Comment: Could you post a link to some sample code or the full code that can be run?

Comment: I haven’t seen this before but just throwing out a wild suggestion: what if you call the key function you want to time out from a coroutine and then cancel the coroutine after 10 seconds?

Comment: Another question I have is can you explain more about this edge case and what you want the user flow to be? It seems like the call isn’t returning but why does that matter really?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `kotlin flow` to get what you want.

**NOTE: This code uses the latest dependency of the location, you will have to modify the basic code of `LocationRequest` if you want to go with the older versions.**

For Dependency Injection:

```
implementation("javax.inject:javax.inject:1")
```

**For location updates**

```
import android.annotation.SuppressLint
import android.location.Location
import android.os.Looper
import com.google.android.gms.location.FusedLocationProviderClient
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationCallback
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationRequest
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationResult
import kotlinx.coroutines.channels.awaitClose
import kotlinx.coroutines.flow.Flow
import kotlinx.coroutines.flow.callbackFlow
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit
import javax.inject.Inject

class LocationHelper @Inject constructor(
    private val client: FusedLocationProviderClient
) {
    @SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
    fun fetchUpdates(): Flow<LatLngLocation> = callbackFlow {
        val locationRequest by lazy {
            LocationRequest.create().apply {
                interval = TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(UPDATE_INTERVAL_SECS)
                fastestInterval = TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(FASTEST_UPDATE_INTERVAL_SECS)
                priority = LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY
            }
        }

        val callBack = object : LocationCallback() {
            override fun onLocationResult(locationResult: LocationResult) {
                super.onLocationResult(locationResult)
                val location = locationResult.lastLocation
                val userLocation = LatLngLocation(
                    latitude = location.latitude,
                    longitude = location.longitude,
                ).apply {
                    locationVal = location
                }
                trySend(userLocation).isSuccess
            }
        }

        client.requestLocationUpdates(locationRequest, callBack, Looper.getMainLooper())
        awaitClose { client.removeLocationUpdates(callBack) }
    }

    companion object {
        const val UPDATE_INTERVAL_SECS = 5L
        const val FASTEST_UPDATE_INTERVAL_SECS = 2L
    }
}

data class LatLngLocation(var latitude: Double, var longitude: Double) {
    var address: String = ""
    var locationVal: Location? = null
}
```

**Collect the updated location using Flow and cancel the updates when you don't need it with the help of `Job`**

```
private var jobLocation: Job? = null

val locationHelper =
            LocationHelper(LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this))
        jobLocation?.cancel()
        jobLocation = lifecycleScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
            locationHelper
                .fetchUpdates()
                .cancellable()
                .collect {
                    launch(Dispatchers.Main) {
                        getLocationUpdates(it.locationVal)
                    }
                }
        }


//Cancel the updates when you don't need it
override fun onPause() {
        jobLocation?.cancel()
        super.onPause()
    }

override fun onDestroy() {
        jobLocation?.cancel()
        super.onDestroy()
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Stopping in a breakpoint to look at if `locationResult.maxWaitTime = 10000` is working we can see:

[image]

> Request[PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY requested=3600000ms fastest=600000ms]

Expanding the all the parameters we also see an obfuscated parameter is set to 10000. Before running the program any further though let's go to the docs to figure out how these 3 values interact.

In [the docs](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/LocationRequest), we see:

> getMaxWaitTime()
> This method is deprecated. Use getMaxUpdateDelayMillis() instead. May be removed in a future release.

Continuing on to the docs explanation for the recommended replacement we have:

> public long getMaxUpdateDelayMillis ()
>
> The longest a location update may be delayed. This parameter controls location batching behavior. If this is set to a value at least 2x larger than the interval specified by getIntervalMillis(), then a device may (but is not required to) save power by delivering locations in batches. If clients do not require immediate delivery, consider setting this value as high as is reasonable to allow for additional power savings.
>
> For example, if a request is made with a 2s interval and a 10s maximum update delay, this implies that the device may choose to deliver batches of 5 locations every 10s (where each location should represent a point in time ~2s after the previous).

Going back to what we see in the debugger it seems that our requested wait time is by default `requested=3600000ms` and `fastest=600000ms`

The docs indicate that we need the `getMaxUpdateDelayMillis` to be at least twice our requested time to have an effect since it is just for batching multiple requests together.

To achieve our desired result of requests returning after 10 seconds lets instead use the `requested` and `fastest` fields. In the debugger we see this is setting properly:

[image]

> Request[PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY requested=10000ms fastest=5000ms]

And after a bunch of testing this isn't really going in a loop. You are observing `lastLocation` with on onSuccessListener but that imply's that somewhere we are calling to get the last location updated.

As a result,             `fusedLocationProviderClient.requestLocationUpdates(locationResult, locationCallback, looper)` must be moved to be called on it's own to get that started.

To be honest after a couple hours this still isn't working on my machine but maybe it will on yours?

Here are some docs I found helpful:

- [Docs on requesting location](https://developer.android.com/training/location/request-updates#addt-resources-samples)
- [Sample app from google albeit using Compose](https://github.com/android/platform-samples/blob/main/samples/location/src/main/java/com/example/platform/location/locationupdates/LocationUpdatesScreen.kt)

In the Compose sample app they show a 3 second interval but it looks like they may be using a new'er version of the library then you are. Depending on your need, a final suggesting is in a separate looper/handler/service from these calls and callbacks you can check to see if permissions are enabled every 5-10 seconds and take action based on that. To reduce those calls you can also restart that looper every time you receive a location data and only check for permissions if it seems there is a gap in the data being sent.